# Есть ли ограничение на количество проектов для деплоя на heroku?

Tags: heroku

Есть ли ограничение на количество проектов для деплоя на heroku? Если пользоваться только выделенным размером памяти для деплоя на бесплатном тарифе. Прошу прощения за элементарный вопрос, не мог найти инфу т.к англ. слабо владею.

Answer (score 1):

Количесво проектов не ограничено. Есть ограничение по работе выших dynos в часах (насколько я помню для free 400 часов/месяц если не привязывали карту и 1000 часов/месяц если привязали ).